# How to call a method with the name passed by parameter?

Tags: ruby, testing

I have a class with some methods

```
class Test
  def add(a,b)
    a+b
  end
  ...
end
```

I want to test, dynamically, if a Class and a Method were defined, and assert the method.
Here is the code and the problem =(

```
def methodInsideDefined?(className, methodName, param1, param2, result)
  if(className.is_a?(Class) && className.method_defined?(:methodName))
    className.new.methodName(param1,param2).eql?(result)
  end
end
```

So if I call:

```
methodInsideDefined?(Test, add, 1, 2, 3)
```

I should get a true value, but I'm getting a:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method ‘add’ for main:Object
```

Please ignore the params number in a static way, I will get to dynamic number of parameters later, but if you have a solution with dynamic number of parameters, please let me know. =D

Yes, I'm a Ruby noobie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
methodInsideDefined?(Test, :add, 1, 2, 3)
```

In your current code you are passing the non-existent *variable* `add` to your function. It  does work if, instead of a variable, you pass the symbol `:add` to the function.

In your function definition it's the other way around. You're using a symbol there instead of the variable. It should be:

```
def methodInsideDefined?(className, methodName, param1, param2, result)
  if className.is_a?(Class) && className.method_defined?(methodName)
    className.new.send(methodName,param1,param2).eql?(result)
  end
end
```

Also note the use of [`send`](http://khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/) in my code. You have to use it when you want to call a method dynamically.

Comment: So simple! Thank you very much @Mischa, I used the symbol inside because I was testing with Pry, and it required the symbol, the `send` was the key here. Worked just fine. I'll try a solution for dynamic params now. Thanks again.